# How to replace Missing Value with Mode

Tags: r, missing-data

```
data <- c("SW",  "E",   "N",   "WNW", "SSE", "SE",  "SE",  "SE",  "E",   "S",   "SE",  "E",   "S",  
 "WNW", "S",   "SE",  "WSW","SW", "NNE","NNW","N",  "ENE","S",  NA ,"SSE","E", 
 "E",  "S",  "SE", "SSW","E",  "E",  "WNW","NW", "ESE","ESE","NW", "E",  NA)
```

I'm new to R. There are some missing value in this attributes. I wanna replace them with mode imputation. What should I do? Appreciate for your help!

Comment: NAs in your dataset aren't real NAs as these are of character types.  So first you need to convert them to actual NAs.  `Rstudio` tag removed as there's nothing to do with IDE.

Comment: What model are you assuming that would allow you to impute the data? You seem to have no other information to use to make a good guess as to what the value might have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode):

```
data <- c("SW",  "E",   "N",   "WNW", "SSE", "SE",  "SE",  "SE",  "E",   "S",   "SE",  "E",   "S",  
 "WNW", "S",   "SE",  "WSW","SW", "NNE","NNW","N",  "ENE","S",  NA ,"SSE","E", 
 "E",  "S",  "SE", "SSW","E",  "E",  "WNW","NW", "ESE","ESE","NW", "E",  NA)


Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

data[is.na(data)] <- Mode(data)
data

 [1] "SW"  "E"   "N"   "WNW" "SSE" "SE"  "SE"  "SE"  "E"   "S"   "SE"  "E"   "S"   "WNW" "S"   "SE"  "WSW" "SW"  "NNE" "NNW" "N"   "ENE" "S"  
[24] "E"   "SSE" "E"   "E"   "S"   "SE"  "SSW" "E"   "E"   "WNW" "NW"  "ESE" "ESE" "NW"  "E"   "E"
```

Comment: how do you do it for a `Data.Frame`?

Comment: @Another.Chemist, you could use `lapply` : `df <- data.frame(c1=data,c2=data); data.frame(lapply(df,\(data) {data[is.na(data)] <- Mode(data);data}))`